# How to be alerted about the ongoing progress of a loop/lapply

Tags: r, loops

In `R`, I will sometimes have a long `for loop` or `lapply` that I want to know the ongoing progress of.

Something like the following is in the spirit of what I want but doesn't work:

`lapply(1:n,function(i) { print(i); MAIN COMPUTATIONS })`

Ideally the above would print `i` at the beginning of each new iteration of the `lapply`.

**QUESTION:** How do I get ongoing progress updates of how many iterations my `lapply` or `for loop` has done?

Comment: Are you using RGui on Windows?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: @DavidRobinson When the `lapply` finally finishes ALL of its iterations, then `i` from `1` to `n` will be printed. However, I want it to print after each individual iteration as a way of alterting me of the progress.

Comment: @Dason I'm using the default R ... The `R Console (64-bit)` with the white window inside of it.

Comment: Yeah you're using RGui.  The output is buffered.  I don't use Windows but there should be an option in one of the dropdown menus to tell it to not buffer the output.  This will slow down your code a little bit though.

Comment: @Dason Can I build a function called `lapply2` or `for2` which enables this dynamic printing of `i`? I would prefer this solution s.t. I don't slow down my other code when I have no need for dynamic printing of `i`. Also what OS do you use?

Comment: I would definitely recommend that you look into the `plyr` package, especially `llply(...,.progress="text")` ...

Comment: @Jase - You might want to check out [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) for a nicer interface to R.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're using RGui on Windows.  There should be an option in one of the menus to tell it to not buffer the output.  Alternatively you could call `flush.console` after every time you print.

```
lapply(1:1000, function(i){print(i); flush.console()})
```

Note that this will slow down the code a little bit.

Comment: Another way would be to just click on the screen whenever I want an update (without including `flush.console()`).

Answer (score 6):

A solution using plyr

```
 l_ply(1:10,function(x) x+1,.progress='text')
```

or you can define your progress using `progress_text`

```
 l_ply(1:10000,function(x) x+1,.progress= progress_text(char = '*'))
|*********************************************************************| 100%
```

or with option print , to get the result of each iteration

```
     l_ply(1:4,function(x) x+1,.progress= progress_text(char = '+'),.print=TRUE)
  |                                 |   0%[1] 2
  |++++++                           |  25%[1] 3
  |+++++++++++++++                  |  50%[1] 4
  |++++++++++++++++++++++           |  75%[1] 5
  |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ |  100%[1]
```

Comment: @Jase You need to thank Hadley. And don't forget parallel option.

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to look at the functions like `winProgressBar`, `tkProgressBar`, or `txtProgressBar`.  The windows and tk versions are nice in that they can show you your progress, but don't clutter your output.