# regarding printing the debugging related information to the screen

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to be alerted about the ongoing progress of a loop/lapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832221/how-to-be-alerted-about-the-ongoing-progress-of-a-loop-lapply)

While debugging a R program, I would like to print the output information to the screen for the debugging purposes. For instance, how to generate something like the following in the same line.

```
"loop= 5", "a=5","b=5"
```

Comment: Literally? Just add a few print lines in your loops. `for(i in 1:5) print("loop =",a[i])` for example.

Comment: Or `message("loop=", a[i])`. ....actually, I think you're trying to use `print` like `cat`. that won't work.

Comment: see the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832221/how-to-be-alerted-about-the-ongoing-progress-of-a-loop-lapply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking @Matthew's suggestion,  the problem may just be that you are attempting to use `print` on several variables/strings at once. This wont work.

If you want to use `print` with strings, you need to give one, single string. And the most effective way of doing this is using `paste()`.
There are also many alternatives, such as `cat` and `sprintf`.   Here is a brief example:

Let's create some sample variables to output
    i <- 3
    a <- letters[1:5]

You may be trying to do this:

```
# This will *NOT* work
print("loop = ", i, "a = ", a[[i]])
```

Instead try one of the following: 
(note: `paste0` is the same as using `paste(..., sep="")`)

```
# using print( paste0 (.) )
print(paste0("loop = ", i, ", a = ", a[[i]]))
#  [1] "loop = 3, a = c

# using cat()
cat("loop = ", i, ", a = ", a[[i]])
#  loop =  3 , a =  c

# using sprintf
sprintf("loop = %d, a = %s", i, a[[i]])
#  [1] "loop = 3, a = c"
```